# Test for equal amount of x and y in string using stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am working on a function which tests to see if there are the same amount of x's and y's in the string. I was hoping someone can give me insight on how to fix this function.
I am assuming that the string only contains x's and y's.
I thought this code looked right but when I traced it with the letters in different orders is didn't work

Here is my code:

```
bbool equal(string Letters){
stack<string>a_stack;
for(int i=0; i<Letters.length(); i++){
    if(s[i]=='x')
        a_stack.push(Letters[i]);
}
for(int j=0; j<Letters.length(); j++){
    if(s[j]=='y')
        a_stack.pop();
}
if(a_stack.empty())
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

}

This is for a homework assignment and I'm required to use a stack.

Comment: What happens if the first character is not an `x`?

Comment: Why are you not just using two counters?

Comment: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is horribly redundant. simply use `return condition;` instead.

Comment: What is `Letters[i].push();` supposed to do? (in other words, you never show a `push` onto `equal_stack`...)

Comment: Should it have `equal_stack.push("foo");` instead of `Letters[i].push();`?

Comment: @5gon12eder I have to use a stack. If I use a counter than a stack would be pointless

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make sense for me.  Why do you have to use a stack?  As you say, it's pointless as the problem can be solved much faster and easier using counters.

Comment: @5gon12eder I know but the professor told us we have to use a stack

Comment: Alright then.  So maybe add this bit of information to your question.

Comment: @5gon12eder it is a just a function to see if there are equal amounts of x's and y's

Comment: A stack isn't really going to do that easily. For example, your code pushes when receiving `x`, but suppose `y` comes first, then `x`. You end up with an ignored `y` and an `x` left on the stack, and though the input fulfills the requirements (equal number of each) you're left with a non-empty stack. [Personally I'd just **do this**](http://ideone.com/JWB5bV). If your prof said use a stack, then perhaps the requirements of the assignment and additional restrictions of the input data are not being clearly communicated here.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just edited the code. What do you think?

Comment: If you're allowed to scan the string twice, it is certainly doable. However, the second loop upon encountering a `y` should return `false` immediately if the stack is already empty, else pop and continue on. And after the loop can simply be consolidated to `return a_stack.empty();` Still not the way I would do it (see prior comment and link), but it would seem you're somewhat boxed.

Comment: When you have more `y` than `x` you'll have a stack underflow. This problem is for counters, not for stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single stack isn't going to work for the reasons mentioned the way you're using it.  You could use two stacks, one for x's and one for y's, then compare the size.

Or, you could use a single stack and push 1 for x's and -1 for y's.  then sum up the stack.  If they're equal, the sum will be 0.

Comment: so how can I use two stacks for a single string?

Comment: If Letters[i] == 'x', push a value in the x_stack, otherwise push it on the y_stack (assuming only x's or y's are in the string).

Comment: that is what I am doing but I keep getting an error when I am pushing

Comment: am I using the push function wrong here?  x_stack.push(Letters[i])

Comment: `a_stack.push(Letters[i]);` is not the problem.  The problem is `a_stack.pop();` when the stack is empty.  Iterate through your code when the string is 'xyy' or 'yx'.  If your code calls `a_stack.pop()' when the stack is empty, it will throw.  If you're going to use a single stack, only push integers (1 for x, -1 for y), then iterate through the stack and sum the values.  sum == 0 means there are the same quantity of xs and ys.  sum > 0, means there are more xs.  sum < 0 means there are more ys.